# Is there somewhere that we can view a graph of the site statistics?

Tags: support, statistics

I could have sworn there were move visitors daily, I am wondering if there is a history graph showing how the site has been progressing in each field as displayed on the current statistics on the sidebar or area 51. I have no clue what to tag this question, sorry.

Comment: Basically, we had an increase which stayed high for quite a while during examination time, then semester got over for a lot of folks, with a drastic decrease in views/etc. That's all... It's climbing up again :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are site-specific stats that are available, but they are only accessible by moderators and administrators, unfortunately.

You can, however, approximate the visits by using something like [Quantcast](http://www.quantcast.com/chemistry.stackexchange.com):
[image]

Comment: Nice thanks, very interesting that graph is. It has a kind of steadiness, but at the same time it does not.

Answer (score 2):

The specific day-to-day analytics are not generally shared with the public, but on occasion I may post limited views of data to illustrate a larger point, like how a site is trending in its overall growth or whatever is being discussed.

[image: Chemistry SE Visits]

Chemistry Stack Exchange traffic correlates strongly with academia usage, as you might expect. You can see this site surge through a course of strong, steady growth starting in September with the start of the new school year. As such, usage dropped off somewhat during the winter holiday break… and what you are seeing now is traffic picking up as everyone is getting back into the the routine of their studies. Nice job. Enjoy!